# How to assign multiple fixed ip address for one domain?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'm running `dnsmasq`,

```
address=/chat.freenode.net/130.239.18.172
address=/chat.freenode.net/140.211.167.105
```

But seems `dnsmasq` only recognize the last record, what should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a file, `say /etc/hosts.chat.freenode.net`, that has the same format as `/etc/hosts` file and list all IP addresses with name in this file:

```
130.239.18.172 chat.freenode.net
140.211.167.105 chat.freenode.net
```

Then add to the `dnsmasq.conf` the following line:

```
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.chat.freenode.net
```

Or put these two lines into `/etc/hosts` if `dnsmasq` is set to read in the `/etc/hosts`.

Then restart `dnsmasq`

Enjoy.

Comment: Yep, easier to maintain

Comment: I guess the only problem with using `/etc/hosts` would be that the local machine would always resolve the first one instead of getting a round-robin distribution from dnsmasq.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII although resolver library would return the first found entry always, the answer is related to the setting `dnsmasq` to read `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 8):

Okay, after nearly 10 years, the setting in the question post is now valid since dnsmasq 2.86 release.

address=/chat.freenode.net/130.239.18.172
address=/chat.freenode.net/140.211.167.105

```
$ host chat.freenode.net 10.0.0.53
Using domain server:
Name: 10.0.0.53
Address: 10.0.0.53#53
Aliases:

chat.freenode.net has address 140.211.167.105
chat.freenode.net has address 130.239.18.172
```

Comment: This is the way. (in 2023)

Answer (score -4):

Copy the existing `ifcfg-etho` to `ifcfg-eth0:0` and change the existing IP to your virtual IP (the one you want to add).

It can be found at **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts**.

Restart the network and try to ping the virtual IP.